# How to modify html tag with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, tags

I am currently working on a website where I need to add content dynamically via javascript. I am working with UIKit (https://getuikit.com/docs/slider).

This is what I want to achieve:

```
<img src="images/photo.jpg" alt="" uk-cover>
```

What I Already tried:

```
img = document.createElement("img");
img.ukcover = "";
```

So how do I add the uk-cover to my img html tag?
Thanks!

Comment: try img.setAttribute("ukcover", "")

Comment: u have a typo in your comment img.setAttribute("uk-cover", "") worksfor me - post your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: thanks i posted my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to set attribute you can use img.setAttribute("uk-cover", "")

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) that

> Sets the value of an attribute on the specified element. If the attribute already exists, the value is updated; otherwise a new attribute is added with the specified name and value.

```js
let img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute('src', 'images/photo.jpg');
img.setAttribute('alt', 'photo');
img.setAttribute('uk-cover', '');
document.body.appendChild(img)
console.log(img);
```

**Please Note:** I have set some default text to `alt` attribute because images with only visual value should have an empty alt attribute set on them.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `setAttribute(propertyName, value)` method.

```
img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute("ukcover", "");
img.setAttribute("src", "images/photo.jpg");
img.setAttribute("alt", "");
```

Comment: doesn't work, because its not a tag property - and its also uk-cover not ukcover

Answer (score 1):

Dot notation does not work with cases having a hyphen. Use `Element.setAttribute`

```
const img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute('uk-cover', "https://picsum.photos/300");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setAttribute()` and pass the second argument as a blank string.

```js
img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute('uk-cover','');
img.src = "https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
document.body.appendChild(img);
```